# Can the kmacro internal format contain literal commands?

Tags: keyboard-macros, key-chord-mode

I'm trying to modify `key-chord.el` so that you can have key-combination specific timeouts and I noticed that `key-chord` uses heuristics to decide when two keys pressed sequentially in a kmacro are intended to form a key chord. I don't completely understand the heuristics yet, but it seems like a better approach would be to detect when the keychord is being executed inside a kmacro, delete the relevant keys from the kmacro, and insert a command in their place. I tried skimming the `kmacro.el` source distributed with emacs and it's not clear to me how to insert an input event that's more complicated than a simple key press into a kmacro, or if only key presses are supported.